# About flask-restful

Tags: flask-restful

Client to use get function:

```
def get_hist_data(exchange_id, instrument_id, frequency, start_date, end_date):
    headers = fill_header()
    body =

    {'exchange_id':exchange_id,'instrument_id':instrument_id,
    'star``t_date':start_date,'end_date':end_date,'frequency':frequency}
    resp = requests.get(stock_tick_url,json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
    print resp.text
Sever side:
```

The result is none when to 'print args'. I know that if the client code change to this: `?xx=xxx&xxx=xxxx` server will work. But change to json, it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I can't tell what kind of help you are asking for. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('exchange_id', type=str, location='args')

parser.add_argument('instrument_id', type=str, location='args')

parser.add_argument('start_date', type=str, location='args')

parser.add_argument('end_date', type=str, location='args')

parser.add_argument('frequency', type=int, location='args')

def get(self):
    args = parser.parse_args()

Comment: here is the server side code, I forget to paste it.